Intersection of product of spheres with linear subspaces
Consider a real vector space $V$ of dimension $3N$ given as a direct sum of $N$ copies of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Let $M$ be the non-linear subspace defined by $\vert\mathbf{v}_i\vert^2 = 1$ for all $i$, where $\mathbf{v}_i$ is a vector in the $i$'th 3-dimensional subspace, a product of 2-spheres.
Let $J$ be a $3N\times 3N$ symmetric real matrix with non-negative eigenvalues defining a quadratic form on $V$, and assume that a non-trivial fraction $0<f<1$ of the eigenvalues of $J$ are zero.
Question: Under what conditions can the intersection of the null space of $J$ with $M$ be empty?
Simpler (?) question: under what conditions is the intersection of a subspace of dimension $3Nf$ with $M$ be empty?
Simpler (??) question: is there any intuition as to the topology of the intersection in general?
Addendum, motivation: this is motivated by the issue of finding the ground state configuration of an array of classical dipoles, where $\mathbf{v}_i$ is the orientation of the $i$'th dipole. The matrix $J$ determines the energy $E$ of a configuration via $E = \sum_{ij=1}^N \sum_{a,b=1}^3 v_i^a J_{ij}^{ab} v_j^b$. In simple cases $J$ has a unique or just a few discrete minimum eigenvalues. Note we can always shift the minimum to zero as this only shifts the energy by a constant. The set of ground states is given by the intersection of the null space of $J$ with the non-linear manifold $M$. It may happen in certain cases that $J$ has an extensive (proportional to $N$) number of zero eigenvalues. My main question is whether it can ever be the case that the intersection of $M$ with the null space is empty when the null space is extensive. The only cases where I know this can happen is when $M$ is a product of 0-spheres ($M$ is the corners of a $N$-sided hypercube), and intuitively it seems that for $k$-spheres with $k>0$ there is always an intersection, but I don't know how to prove it.

THis is clearly a problem you have thought a lot about. It might help us if you [edit] the question to tell us where it comes from, and to show us some examples in low dimenstons.
